# In Emacs, editing C, sort-fields not working, or stating sole completion. Why?

Tags: emacs, c

In Emacs, editing C, and trying to execute sort-fields doesn't seem to be working. I enter M-x sort-fields after highlighting a region.  At one point it was letting me pass a field number, but then suddenly it stopped, and now it reports `[Sole Completion]` when I enter space to pass the field number.  I was thinking that maybe in C-mode it doesn't like that command, but I'm not sure.  Any guidance on how to get this to work, or what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK sort-fields has no interactive way to specify the field number, you have to give it as a C-u argument. E.g for the 3rd field: `C-u 3 M-x sort-fields`